# Gulp development workflow and the 'dist' folder

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm relatively new to gulp and am using it as a taskrunner to concatenate and compile .js and sass/css files. Those aspects are currently working in a development environment.

What I'm confused about is a workflow issue. Right now my concatentated files are in these folders:

```
-css (myapp.css)
-js (myappconcat.js)
```

If I'm working locally, I don't want to minify these yet for debugging purposes (right?).

However, reading up on gulp, I see that build tasks are normally set up to minify the assets into a 'dist' folder for production. How do I manage this in my HTML files?

For example, in my development HTML file I would have CSS and js includes like so:

```
<link href="/css/myapp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myappconcat.js"></script>
```

However, when I build my minified files to a 'dist' directory, I would have to change the paths in the includes above for every HTML file.

How does one go about managing a gulp build to a dist folder without having to change the paths in each include in the HTML? Similarly, when I minify for production, don't I also have to change the .js and CSS filenames in the HTML includes as well? Or should I be using minified files in development?

EDIT: Here's the basic site structure:

```
wwwroot
   -.html files
   - gulpfile.js
   - package.json
   /css
     -main.css
   /dist
   /js
   /scss
```

AND the gulpfile.js

```
// Required gulp modules
var gulp      = require('gulp'),
    concat    = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify    = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename    = require('gulp-rename'),
    sass      = require('gulp-sass'),
    maps      = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    del       = require('del'),
    jshint    = require('gulp-jshint'),
    stylish   = require('jshint-stylish'),
    gutil     = require( 'gulp-util' ),
    merge     = require('merge-stream'),
    imagemin  = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    cleanCSS  = require('gulp-clean-css');

// error reporter in progress
var reportError = function( err ) {

  gutil.beep();

  var title = 'Error';

  if( err.plugin === 'gulp-sass' ) {
    title = 'SCSS Compilation Error';
  }

  var msg = '\n============================================\n\n';
  msg += title += '\n\n';
  msg += err.message + '\n\n';
  msg += '============================================';

  gutil.log( gutil.colors.red( msg ) );

  if( err.plugin === 'gulp-sass' ) {

   this.emit('end');

  }

};

// Concatenate .js files with lint-js as the dependency
gulp.task("concatScripts", ["lint-js"], function() {
   return gulp.src([
       'js/*.js'
       ,'node_modules/jquery-placeholder/jquery.placeholder.js'
       ])
   .pipe(maps.init())
   .pipe(concat('zConcat.js'))
   .pipe(maps.write('./'))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));//write to separate dir than src otherwise 
     overwrites itself!
});

// Minify .js files with concatscripts as the dependency
gulp.task("minifyScripts", ["concatScripts"], function() {
  return gulp.src("dist/js/zConcat.js")
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename('zConcat.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

// .js Linter for catching errors when any .js changes
gulp.task('lint-js', function () {
  return gulp.src([
      'js/*.js',       // all custom .js
      //'!_js/public/js/html5shiv.js', // ignore shiv
    ])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish));    // color-coded line by line errors
});

// Compile sass files
gulp.task('compileSass', function() {
  return gulp.src("scss/main.scss")
      .pipe(maps.init())
      .pipe(sass(
       {
       outputStyle: 'expanded'
       }
     ).on( 'error',  reportError) ) //sass.logError
      .pipe(maps.write('./'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

// Minify CSS after compiling
 gulp.task('minifyCSS', () => {
   return gulp.src('css/*.css')
   .pipe(maps.init())
   .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
   .pipe(rename('main.min.css'))
   .pipe(maps.write('./'))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

// Watch and process SASS and .js file changes
gulp.task('watchFiles', function() {
  gulp.watch(['scss/**/*.scss','scss/*.scss'], ['compileSass']);
  gulp.watch( 'css/*.css', ['minifyCSS']);
  gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', ['concatScripts']);
});
```

Comment: Hey Tass! I'd be more than happy to help, but to give you an answer geared towards your current project, could you explain how you have the project folder set up? E.g. the root folder is named "mysite" and inside you have your index.html, contact.html, gulpfile.js, myapp.css, myappconcat.js etc. Do you have folders set up for css and js? or is everything directly under your root folder? Also, if you post your current gulpfile.js then I can help critique your current set up to give you a better idea of a development workflow!

Comment: Thanks, @jstoobz! I posted the folder structure and gulpfile.js above...

Comment: @jstoobz, if you're out there, I'm all ears. :)

Answer (score 0):

this might be late, but no one answered.

For me, I create two production files (or folders if the output is more than one file, with each folder containing a set of files). One is minified, and the other is not.

For development and testing purposes, I use the non-minified version. Once the product is ready for production, I retest but using the minified version, and typically this is the one I release.

So I write my scripts to produce two files (or file sets if I have more than a file to produce).

Hope this helps.